# How to connect an extra monitor and a thunderbolt (LaCie) harddrive on a MacBook Pro (13" mid 2012)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, display, thunderbolt

I have a 13 inch Mid 2012 MacBook Pro and I want to connect my LaCie Thunderbolt hard drive and my extra 21" Monitor but the MacBook Pro has only one thunderbolt port...

How it will be possible?

Comment: Thanks Heiko !
Unfortunelly, my MacbookPro has only one thunderbolt port, the same for my Hard drive...
Anyway, do you know any TB hub with three ports ? (one to connect to the computer)
I've been trying to find unsuccessfully... Maybe Apple is controlling the third-parties to prevent its own market...?!?

Answer (score 1):

If either your LaCie Thunderbolt Drive offers more than one Thunderbolt port ([https://www.lacie.com/se/products/product.htm?id=10621](like this one)), or you have a native Thunderbolt display, you can "daisy-chain" them:

- connect one device to your macbook (the one with two Thunderbolt ports, e.g. the drive)
- connect the other device (e.g. your display) to the second Thunderbolt port of the first device (e.g. your drive)

If none of your Thunderbolt devices support daisy-chaining (i.e. don't offer a second TB port), then you would need a Thunderbolt Hub.

Another possibility would be to connect the hard drive via USB, if it can, [https://www.lacie.com/se/products/product.htm?id=10599](like this one).

One caveat though: this should work for any thunderbolt display. If you want to use the DisplayPort adapter, you should check whether it works when it is not connected directly to your Mac.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my Macbook Pro is not a Retina but a mid 2012 non-retina MacBook; it has just one thunderbolt port and the available hubs has only two ports, so, one to connect to the Mac and other to to the device (display or drive. My LaCie 4Tb drive has only one thunderbolt port... does it means "no daisy-chaining for me" ?

Comment: If your disk and monitor each have one port only, that means no daisychaining. But using a hub should still be possible. The Idea of a hub is to connect multiple devices, so, even if the hub only offers 'two ports', I guess that means two plus the one connecting to the computer. I see the higher rist though in whether your thunderbolt to display adapter will work on a hub as opposed to only directly on the mac. Or are you using a native thunderbolt display?